# MYSQL Balance Sheet Design

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on creating an ERD Diagram to map out a MYSQL database. One of my entities in the ERD Diagram is Balance Sheet. How I have it setup right now is:

**Company**
PK Company ID 
Company Name

**Balance Sheet**
PK Balance Sheet ID
FK Company ID
Year
Month

I then break each part of the Balance Sheet into entities that are specific to a balance sheet row. For instance, for Accounts Receivable I have:

**Balance Sheet_AR**
PK BalanceSheet_AR_ID
FK BalanceSheet_ID
Value

I have a ton of tables that are specific to the Balance Sheet row; however, I was thinking I could do something like:

**Balance Sheet_Role**
PK BalanceSheet_Role_ID
FK BalanceSheet_ID
BalanceSheet Role
Value

Would doing the Balance Sheet_Role method cause any complications? Thank you in advance for any help! Please let me know if there is a better way to set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The role version should work just fine because I will specify the balance sheet based on a month or year so the records for BalanceSheet_Role will display all roles made within that month or year